# Is there a way to get only the first N search results with LDAP?

Tags: .net, ldap

Is there a good way retrieve only the first N results with an LDAP query, to save load on the server and increase response time?

The use case is, for example, progressive AJAX based name pickers (via an LDAP to HTTP gateway which will want to limit the query size to the backing LDAP directory) that will find all results starting with the letters the user has typed so far.

Example code using .NET 4.5 System.DirectoryServices.Protocols would be appreciated, but is not necessary, because if I know what the actual protocol requirements are, I can figure out how to send the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what the Java [PagedResultsControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/PagedResultsControl.html) is for. There is one in [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.pageresultrequestcontrol.aspx) as well. These things implement the protocol for you and just provide an API.

Comment: This addresses neither the lower level protocol information necessary to get paged results, nor the .NET way to achieve it with System.DirectoryServices.Protocol--a javax resource does me no good.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I was mistaken to assume Java and JNDI, but surely there is one of these in .NET? If so it would certainly take care of the protocol details for you, that' the whole point.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that there is a `PageResultRequestControl` in s.ds.p; evidently support for this feature is not universal.

Comment: I edited the post and it still will not let me remove the downvote; sorry.  Ah, I don't have enough rep here to edit unilaterally.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Fixed it myself.

Comment: .NET reference for s.ds.p is actually http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.pageresultrequestcontrol.aspx

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Thanks, incorporated that.

Comment: You may want to use the search size limit settings for this. Not sure how the options are exposed in .NET.  Using ldapsearch --hostname localhost -p 1389 --baseDn 'uid=user.0,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com' \
     --searchScope base --sizeLimit 5 -> Would only return 5 entries. This maybe faster than a paged results as you will need to redo the search each time a character is typed.

Comment: @jeemster Actually, I tried the size limit before turning to paging.  Even if I only want the first say 20, if more exit, then an exception is thrown.  No fun but that is the empirical behavior of .NET against TDS--IIRC the error is actually generated server-side.  Paging is now working fantastically well.

Answer (score 2):

Good answer by EJP. Note that while an LDAP client can restrict itself to just the first N results easily enough, the ordering entries returned from a search is *not repeatable*. That is, the order of entries returned in a search result is not only not defined, it is not guaranteed to be repeated, even on the same connection milliseconds later. LDAP clients which are sensitive to ordering may experience failure or inexplicable results.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that; my utility interface to LDAP also creates `SortRequestControl`  for that purpose as required.  Furthermore, although I would not count on it as it may lead to horrible future bugs, my experience is that TDS does in fact return results in a deterministic order, probably based on the indexes of the backing DB2 database.  Yes, I realize this is an unspecified implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific purpose ( autocomplete suggestions ) I would go with the ldap sizelimit instead of paged results. Here's the difference:

**Size limit**

You are interested in the first xx objects. You do not care about the rest and you will not need the rest.

**Paged results**

You are interested in *ALL* objects, but you want to retrieve them in batches / *pages* of xx objects per single page. You might eventually need to get all of the objects from the server.

The apparent overhead here is that with paged results, the server has to remember the state of your search and resume it appropriately when you request the next page. As this is usually unnecessary for an autocomplete lists ( unless you want to have the option to expand the autocomplete list further on-demand ), you might save your servers of some extra load using a sizelimit than using paged results.

I am no .NET programmer, but Google found this, it might be of interest for you:
[system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.sizelimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.sizelimit.aspx)

For more details, you may also see the RFC pages ( search for sizelimit there ):
[rfc1777](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1777.txt)

Comment: `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.Protocol` are very different APIs.  They are not related.

Comment: Wrong API and see my comments to other answer about `sizeLimit`.

Comment: Okay, then, what about this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchrequest.sizelimit.aspx

Comment: Copied the wrong link first time - now it points to the inntended documentation in Protocols namespace. Anyway, there is no difference in ordering between paged results-based and size-limited search. And as for AD, it seems to be pretty consistent in the ordering process.